# Display the list of candidates' names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

- candidates (candidat_id, first_name, name)
- files (file_id, candidat_id, category, operation)

I want to display the list, sorted in alphabetical order of the names, of candidates who have more than one examination file with the same category and the same operation.

Comment: So what's stopping you? You've stated what you want, but what are you asking? [so] isn't a free coding service, it's a Q&A site.

Comment: How can i display the list sorted in alphabetical order of the names of the candidates who have more than one examination file with the same category and the same operation?

Comment: Using SQL. For starters, if you search "order data in SQL" in your favourite search engine, you'll get plenty of information

Comment: i know how to display data in alphabetical order my problem is in (the same categry and the same operation

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Also note that homework related questions are expected to prove some extra effort!

Answer (score 0):

if you group the files by candidat_id & category & operation, then the dubs will have a count above 1

```
SELECT candidat_id, category, operation
, COUNT(file_id) AS files
FROM files
GROUP BY candidat_id, category, operation
HAVING COUNT(file_id) > 1
```

If you group that by the candidate, then you can use it to get the names

```
SELECT first_name, name
FROM candidates
WHERE candidat_id IN (
  SELECT candidat_id
  FROM 
  (
     SELECT candidat_id, category, operation
     FROM files
     GROUP BY candidat_id, category, operation
     HAVING COUNT(file_id) > 1
  ) q
  GROUP BY candidat_id
)
ORDER BY first_name, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
select f.candidat_id, f.file_id, f.category, f.operation, c.first_name, c.name -- to get file list with candidate or select c.name, fltr.cnt -- get candidate list with file_cnt
  from files f
  join candidates c
    on f.candidat_id = c.candidat_id
  join (
        select candidat_id, category, operation, count(*) cnt
          from files 
          group by 1,2,3
         having count(*) > 1
       )fltr
    on f.candidat_id = fltr.candidat_id 
   and f.category = fltr.category 
   and f.operation = fltr.operation 
 order by c.name asc
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be.
First: Get the list of candidates has more than one operation file on same category,
Then: Get the names of the list of candidates, and order by name this candidates list.

Here you can create a CTE (for easy read the query)

```
WITH operations ( candidat_id)
AS
    (
    SELECT Candidat_id
    From #files
    GROUP BY candidat_id, category, operation
    HAVING COUNT (candidat_id) >1
    )

SELECT
    candidates.first_name 
FROM
    operations as op INNER JOIN #candidates as candidates
        ON (op.candidat_id = candidates.candidat_id)
ORDER BY
    candidates.first_name
```

And other way can be, the same approacho but all togheter

```
SELECT 
     f.Candidat_id, c.first_name
From #files as f INNER JOIN #candidates AS c
        ON (f.candidat_id = c.candidat_id)
GROUP BY f.candidat_id, f.category, f.operation, c.first_name
HAVING COUNT (f.candidat_id) >1
ORDER BY c.first_name
```

In two solutions you use the pk fields to join, so the performance must be good

Answer (score 0):

You can find the candidates having more than one examination file with same category and operation, and then use `EXISTS` to find the candidate details.

**Query**

```
select t1.* from candidates as t1
where exists(
    select 1 from(
        select candidate_id, count(file_id) as files
        from files 
        group by candidate_id, category, operation
        having count(file_id) > 1
    ) as t2
    where t1.candidate_id = t2.candidate_id
)
order by first_name, name;
```